# SQL - getting the rows that aren't there

Tags: mysql

Title might sound strange but I'll try to explain the problem as easy as possible. Let's start with example. I got a table with 2 columns - id, ip. Let's say I got 3  rows with id 2,3,5. Now, I need to get any row that isn't between id 1 AND 5, which is clearly 1 and 4. Currently I'm stuck with this query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM `votes` 
WHERE ip = "1.1.1.1."  
AND question_id BETWEEN 1 AND 5
```

Comment: So the rows where question_id is lower than 2 or higher than 5?

Comment: "any row that isn't between 1 and 5"... Wouldn't that be `AND NOT (question_id BETWEEN 1 AND 5)`?  Where do rows 1 and 4 come in?  I'm not really clear on what you're trying to do here or why.

Comment: No, from the query that I wrote I'd get 3 results(with id 2, another with id 3 and another with id 5) all having the same ip 1.1.1.1.,but what I'm not getting in this query is 1 and 4(which isn't even in my database) but I need to get those 2 left queries in some way.

Comment: @DonatasPetrauskas: If there *are* no rows with ID 1 and 4 then that would explain why you're not getting them.  Maybe you can do something like `WHERE question_id NOT IN (SELECT question_id FROM votes)`?  Out of curiosity, why do you need to select data which doesn't exist?

Comment: Let's say I got 3 apples with ids of 2,3 and 5, what I don't have is apples with ids of 1 and 4, and I need a query to get these two rows, I don't know how to explain this situation simplier.

Comment: @DonatasPetrauskas: I understand that part, but the point is that there *are no* "apples" with IDs of 1 and 4.  I only ask because it's *highly* irregular to want to select nonexistent data and is *very often* a sign that something else is wrong with the design.  Not guaranteed, but commonly the case.  And providing even a correct answer to an XY problem wouldn't be very helpful to you.

Comment: @David, it is common practice in mysql/sql to have a table of values or dates that are used for determining the absence of data. For instance, the comment I wrote to the Answer below by Alex. A real-world example there is a table with 6k rows of every `Date` over a 20 year time-frame. I per Date. And they want sales by Day for a given month. If there were not sales on Sundays, and a few Tuesdays, now you have problems. So this is not an XY Problem

Answer (score 2):

sounds bizarre but this is what many do.

create a helper table. Use it for left joins

```
create table amfn
(   -- All My Favorite Numbers  
    id int auto_increment primary key,
    theWhat char(1) null
)engine=MyIsam;   --  <----- somewhat important

insert amfn(theWhat) values (null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null); -- 10
insert amfn(theWhat) select theWhat from amfn;
insert amfn(theWhat) select theWhat from amfn;
insert amfn(theWhat) select theWhat from amfn;
insert amfn(theWhat) select theWhat from amfn;
insert amfn(theWhat) select theWhat from amfn;
insert amfn(theWhat) select theWhat from amfn;
insert amfn(theWhat) select theWhat from amfn;
insert amfn(theWhat) select theWhat from amfn;
insert amfn(theWhat) select theWhat from amfn;
insert amfn(theWhat) select theWhat from amfn;
insert amfn(theWhat) select theWhat from amfn;
insert amfn(theWhat) select theWhat from amfn;
insert amfn(theWhat) select theWhat from amfn;
insert amfn(theWhat) select theWhat from amfn;
insert amfn(theWhat) select theWhat from amfn;
insert amfn(theWhat) select theWhat from amfn;
insert amfn(theWhat) select theWhat from amfn;

select count(*),min(id),max(id) from amfn;
+----------+---------+---------+
| count(*) | min(id) | max(id) |
+----------+---------+---------+
|  1310720 |       1 | 1310720 |
+----------+---------+---------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

### Your Schema:

```
create table votes
(   question_id int not null,
    ip varchar(20) not null
);
insert votes (question_id,ip) values (1,'xxxx'),(2,'1.1.1.1'),(3,'1.1.1.1'),(4,'1.6.1.1'),(5,'1.1.1.1');
```

### The Query:

```
select a.id,v.question_id,v.ip
from amfn a
left join votes v
on v.question_id=a.id and v.ip='1.1.1.1'
where a.id between 1 and 5 and v.question_id is null;
+----+-------------+------+
| id | question_id | ip   |
+----+-------------+------+
|  1 |        NULL | NULL |
|  4 |        NULL | NULL |
+----+-------------+------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)     <------------- boy that is fast
```

### Edit (to show Conrad Frix the time differences).

My above approach to create 5242880 rows, `23.5` seconds. Conrad's approach, `168.5` seconds. I will stick with my approach :>

Comment: You might want to wrap up the tally table creation in a proc see [How to create a tally table in mysql](http://www.solomonson.com/content/how-create-tally-table-mysql)

Comment: that would be painfully slow by comparison, @ConradFrix, but I will test it in a second and let ya know

Comment: not sure why you think that, or even why it matters. Creating the tally table should only be done once.

Comment: ok I can be wrong, but it comes from experience in onsy-twosy inserting rows.

Comment: edited bottom to show the timing differences @ConradFrix, see [pastie](http://pastie.org/10372888)

Answer (score 1):

A really unusual request;

But you may get what you want by creating an auxiliary sequence of `1..5`, then select all the ids from this sequence where there's no matching entry in the `votes` table.

```
SELECT id 
FROM (
  SELECT 1 AS id UNION ALL 
  SELECT 2 UNION ALL 
  SELECT 3 UNION ALL 
  SELECT 4 UNION ALL 
  SELECT 5 UNION ALL 
) AS temp 
WHERE temp.id NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT question_id FROM votes);
```

Comment: it is actually a common request. It is not uncommon to have helper tables for numbers, or even every `Date` in a 20 year period for daily sales numbers

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I find the solution -

I made new column for each question_id and all ip fields I filled with NULL, after that I use this logic in SQL query:

```
SELECT question_id
FROM  `votes` 
WHERE (ip =  'NULL' OR ip = ?)
GROUP BY question_id
HAVING COUNT(*) - COUNT(DISTINCT question_id) = 0
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 1
```

And in result I get one random row that haven't been used yet, because it searches for duplicates, and if any duplicates are found they are removed from search. I hope I wrote this understandable